# Quartz Scheduler do not perform when application is hidden

Tags: java, swing, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I wrote a java application which should run automatically . I used **Quartz Scheduler** in here . In my application , It never close from closing UI s. It can close by shout down the PC or exiting from the System tray.

I put a exact time to start the scheduler automatically while application is running in background. But It dosen't work .

Here are the steps which I followed,

This my main class,

**BackupSystemv01.java**

```
public class BackupSystemv01
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        new BackupSystemv01();
        boolean isDisplay = false;
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot set a look and feel . ");
        }

        if (args.length == 0)
        {
            isDisplay = true;
        } else
        {
            isDisplay = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0]);
        }

        LocationOperator locationOperator = new LocationOperator();
        SaveFileLocations lastRecord = locationOperator.getLastRecord();  

        BackUpModeOperator backUpModeOperator = new BackUpModeOperator();
        backUpModeOperator.createBackUpMode();

        BackUpMode backUpMode = backUpModeOperator.getBackUpMode(1);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int day_of_week = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        int HOUR = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int MINUTE = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        AutoBackUp autoBackUp = new AutoBackUp();

        if (backUpMode != null)
        {
            if (backUpMode.isMode() == true)
            {
                String day = backUpMode.getDay();
                String[] split = day.split(",");
                for (String split1 : split)
                {
                    Integer dt = Integer.parseInt(split1);

                    if (dt == day_of_week)
                    {
                        if (backUpMode.getBackUpTime() != null)
                        {
                            Time backUpTime = backUpMode.getBackUpTime();
                            String toString = backUpTime.toString();

                            String[] split2 = toString.split(":");
                            Integer hour = 0;
                            Integer minute = 0;
                            for (int j = 0; j < split2.length; j++)
                            {
                                hour = Integer.parseInt(split2[0]);
                                minute = Integer.parseInt(split2[1]);
                            }

                            if (hour == HOUR && minute == MINUTE)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    autoBackUp.createAutoBackUp(hour, minute);
                                } catch (SchedulerException ex)
                                {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else
                            {
                                HomeFrame instance = HomeFrame.getInstance();
                                instance.setVisible(isDisplay);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                HomeFrame instance = HomeFrame.getInstance();
                instance.setVisible(isDisplay);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

schduler class,

**AutoBackUp.java**

```
public class AutoBackUp
{

    Scheduler scheduler;

    int dayHour;
    int dayMinute;

    public void createAutoBackUp(int hour, int minute) throws SchedulerException
    {
        scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        JobKey backUpJobKey = new JobKey("backUpJob", "backUpGroup");

        TriggerKey backUpTriggerKey = new TriggerKey("backUpTrigger", "backUpTriggerGroup");

        boolean checkExists = scheduler.checkExists(backUpJobKey);

        dayHour = hour;
        dayMinute = minute;

        scheduleJob(AutoBackupCreator.class, checkExists, backUpJobKey, backUpTriggerKey, dayHour, dayMinute);

    }

    private void scheduleJob(Class c, boolean checkExists, JobKey jobKey, TriggerKey triggerKey, int day_hour, int day_minute)
    {
        JobDetail jobDetail = null;

        if (c.isInstance(new AutoBackupCreator()))
        {            
            jobDetail = newJob(AutoBackupCreator.class).withIdentity(jobKey).build();
        }

//        Date providedDate = todayAt(day_hour, day_minute, 0);
//        Date currentDate = new Date();
//
//        System.out.println("Print Fourth Line");
//        
//        if (currentDate.before(providedDate))
//        {
//            System.out.println("todayAt() can be perfomed");
//        } else
//        {
//            System.out.println("tomorrowAt() can be perfomed");
//        }

        Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity(triggerKey)
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(24).repeatForever())
                .startAt((todayAt(day_hour, day_minute, 0))).build();

        try
        {
            if (checkExists)
            {
                scheduler.start();
                scheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerKey, trigger);
                System.out.println("Job Re-scheduled");
            } else
            {
                scheduler.start();
                scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
                System.out.println("Job Scheduled");
            }
        } catch (SchedulerException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Following class is my job class,

**AutoBackupCreator.java**

```
public class AutoBackupCreator implements Job
{

    public static File temp;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException
    {
        runAutomatedBackUp();
    }

    public void runAutomatedBackUp()
    {

    }

    public Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp()
    {
        Date date = new Date();
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        return timestamp;
    }

}
```

Have any ideas for how to correctly run application ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please reduce your code to minimal version that still replicates your error - it will be easier for others to read.

Comment: You should try to use a debugger to see if execution even reaches the point where you create the scheduler. And what happens next.